# Why are the Eclipse colors so messed up with XFCE?

Tags: linux, eclipse, xfce

I recently changed my Linux desktop from KDE to XFCE4. Now Eclipse looks terrible. I have deleted all the .gtkrc* files from my home directory and have been trying all kinds of settings in the XFCE Settings Manager itself. I've tried different XFCE themes as well as different Eclipse themes. I've also tried changing Eclipse's Window > Preferences > Appearance > Theme > Gtk|Classic|Default to no avail. Anyone know how to make these colors sane? [image: eclipse]

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this problem can be some of .gtkrc-* files or settings in the shortcut command. So, try to launch eclipse from the eclipse folder. 
If after that you will be have this problem again, try to install [Jeeeyul's Eclipse Themes](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jeeeyuls-eclipse-themes) and after that you have to go to Window->Preferences-General->Appearance->Jeeeyul's Themes and customise eclipse UI.

If you don't like this theme, try click to [image: [Jeeeyul's Eclipse Themes plugin button] and choose something like Setting gtkrc, and confirm rewrite it file and in the Window->Preferences-General->Appearance choose theme GTK.

If it didn't help you, try to lauch eclipse with command

> env GTK2_RC_FILES=/usr/share/themes/%you_theme_name%/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:/home/%user%/.gtkrc-eclipse '/path_to_eclipse/eclipse'